# how to play blob video in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework, html5-video

i am building a mobile app with a=ionic,i want to be able to play a blob file from uploaded video but i got this in the console

```
unsafe:blob:http://localhost:8100/3d42df5b-d852-4cac-83d8-af0c6d514b04 net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

Here is my code

```
<input type="file"accept="video/*" #fileInput name="proPics" (change)="onSelectedFile($event)">

    preview(files) {
        var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        this.vidURL = URL.createObjectURL(files)
    }
    onSelectedFile(event){
        this.selectedFile = <File>event.target.files[0]
        this.preview(this.selectedFile)
    }
```

When i tried to upload a video file, i got that in the console, please I need your help, what did i do wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do it like this on Html :

```
<input type="file" accept="video/*" (change)="onSelectedFile($event)">

<video 
  *ngIf="prev_url" 
  [src]="prev_url" 
  style="width:300px; height:300px;" 
  controls></video>
```

on ts file :

```
  prev_url : any;

  constructor(
    private sanitizer : DomSanitizer
  ) {}

  onSelectedFile(ev) {
    let file = ev.target.files[0];
    var URL = window.URL;
    this.prev_url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(URL.createObjectURL(file));
    console.log(this.prev_url)
  }
```

here the working [sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-m8zd1m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)