# How to play blob video (avi, mov) in Angular14?

Tags: angular, typescript, google-chrome, angular14, avi

I have had this issue for a while
but did not know how o fix it.

I have found this similar question: [how to play blob video in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62688010/how-to-play-blob-video-in-angular).
But the problem is that even demo in the answear does noot compatible with "avi", and "mov".
I am using latest version of Chrome and it does not show me a selected video.

on html template file:

```html
<input type="file" accept="video/*" (change)="onSelectedFile($event)">

<video 
  *ngIf="prev_url" 
  [src]="prev_url" 
  style="width:300px; height:300px;" 
  controls></video>
```

on ts file:

```js
export class AppComponent  {
  prev_url : any;

  constructor(
    private sanitizer : DomSanitizer
  ) {}

  onSelectedFile(ev) {
    let file = ev.target.files[0];
    var URL = window.URL;
    this.prev_url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(URL.createObjectURL(file));
    console.log(this.prev_url)
  }
}
```

here the working [sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-m8zd1m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

P.S. I also have tried a "vg-player", but neeeeeh it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
export class AppComponent  {
  prev_url: SafeUrl;

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  onSelectedFile(ev) {
    let file = ev.target.files[0];
    var URL = window.URL;
    this.prev_url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(URL.createObjectURL(file));
    console.log(this.prev_url);
  }
}
```